# Insertion Sort Algorithm Analysis

Tags: algorithm, insertion-sort

I am confused with the cost and times of the insertion sort algorithm in the book, "Introduction to Algorithms" 2nd Edition by CLRS (page 25).

Here is the algorithm with cost and times:

```
Insertion-Sort(A)                        cost   times
1. for j <- 2 to length[A]                c1    n
2.     do key <- A[j]                     c2    n-1
3.       //Insert A[j] into the           0     n-1
         //sorted sequence A[1..j-1]
4.     i <- j - 1                         c4    n-1
5.     while i > 0 and A[i] > key         c5    sum_{j=2}^n t_j
6.         do A[i+1] <- A[i]              c6    sum_{j=2}^n (t_j-1)
7.         i <- i - 1                     c7    sum_{j=2}^n (t_j-1)
8.     A[i+1] <- key                      c8    n-1
```

I do not understand, why the value of

```
"times" is equal to n
```

for the outer for loop in line 1 above.

Suppose we have an array "A" like below:

```
A = [5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3]
```

then the length of the array is 6.

So,

```
for j <- 2 to length[A]
```

would mean, we iterate from index 2 to index 6, which is 5 times.

In that case, I am thinking, for the above outer for loop, we are iterating (n-1) times, if n is the total number of elements in the array.

So, I am unsure why the value of "times" for just the Line 1 (that is the out for loop) is n instead of (n-1).

Thanks.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I think they have in mind something along the following lines. A loop

```
for j <- 2 to n
    do stuff
```

is equivalent to this:

```
j <- 2
while j <= n
    do stuff
    j <- j+1
```

which will test its condition for `j` equal to 2, 3, ..., `n`, *and* `n+1`. So it will need to do `n` comparisons, even though the loop body only executes `n` times.

It may be helpful to consider an extreme case: suppose n=2. Then we will: set j=2, check j <= n (yes), do stuff, set j=3, check j <= n (no), done. Two comparisons of `j` against `n`, not just one.

Comment: Though this is likely what CLRS had in mind, I note that there is not a *requirement* that a for-loop be implemented as you describe. A for loop could be implemented as `j = 2; start: if  (j == n) goto end; { do stuff } j = j + 1; goto start; end : { do stuff } ... ` and now the comparison only happens once when n is 2. This requires that we know that `j <= n`, but of course, *knowing that* requires one more comparison!  So there is no free lunch here.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. (Though most compilers wouldn't choose to duplicate the loop body in that fashion, I think.) And there's no particular reason why *number of comparisons* should be the thing to count anyway. But I can't think of any other thought process that would have led the authors to write what they did. (Unless they just made a mistake. Even people as smart as the authors of CLRS make mistakes sometimes.)

Comment: Number of comparisons is usually what is counted in comparison sorts, but of course usually what you care about is number of comparisons of *elements*, not of *indices*.

Comment: Another way to characterize the situation is to say *let us define n as the number of times the outer loop runs*. Now we can determine the cost of the loop as a function of n, determine it to be n-squared, and then say that there is a sublinear relationship between the size of the array and n. But that's a pretty convoluted way to think about it.

Comment: As you say, the usual convention is to ignore everything other than element comparisons because those (unlike index comparisons) can be arbitrarily expensive. But it's possible that the authors were in a sorting-algorithm-analysis frame of mind and therefore inclined to count comparisons rather than anything else. (But you can see them counting things other than comparisons elsewhere in the table.)

Comment: Eric, the text actually explicitly says that `n` is the length of the array (at least in my copy, which is a different edition from the questioner's) so you can't let them off the hook that way :-).

Comment: The `times` column just counts how many times the line is visited in an execution of the algorithm. It's not counting index comparisons so much as counting the number of times that line executes; note that they even count how many times the *comment* is visited, but of course the `cost` column for the comment is 0 because it takes no time to 'execute' a comment. The technique used by the authors is agnostic of which operations you want to count, since they left the costs per line as variables; if you only want to count comparisons between list elements, set all the costs except `c5` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.  In my opinion, it is disappointing the authors did not clearly discuss their intent on how they determined the cost function for each of the lines in this Pseudo-code.  Very bad way to impress a student or students, or working professionals (like myself) who are picking up algorithm analysis after 2 decades of gap!

Thanks again to all.  You all just are amazing, every single time I needed help.

Answer (score 0):

Let consider an array

```
int array={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

The loop starts from 2 and ends at 9

```
for j <- 2 to length[A]
```

This condition checked for 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
The number of times the condition checked  is equal to 8,
but it also checks for 10 and the loop get terminated
So the number of times the condition checked is equal to 9.
That is equal to number elements in the array.

```
n=9
```